# Google Maps inside a Spotify App

Tags: google-maps, spotify

I'm trying to include a Google Maps instance inside a Spotify app that I'm working on (with the v3 Google Maps Javascript API).

I included the following locations in Spotify's permissions manifest.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com
http://csi.gstatic.com
http://maps.gstatic.com
```

The javascript console is showing a warning: "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined" and my Google Maps implementation doesn't load.

Has anyone successfully done this? Any tips?

Comment: After changing manifest don't forget to close and start Spotify Application.

Comment: having the same problem here. @user523513: did you manage to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but this [demo](https://github.com/mager/spotify-apps-tutorial) shows how to display a Polymaps object in Spotify.